# Website download adobe reader could not open PDF because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to login company tracking website and download documents from file in C drive, while opening downloaded documents from C drive I am getting error i.e.

> *Adobe Reader could not open pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged*

Can you advise is there any other way to download PDF file from website?

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
        Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub DowloadSingleFile()
    Dim FileURL As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String

    FileURL = "https://expo.expeditors.com/expotr/expotr?action=com.expd.webapp.tracking.action.document.DocumentImageDownloadWebAction&Type=Image.Get&xref=IVP9OABdjwlQyfAP4d8VNzKeBtYse1TlCWJmb5gzyMxbwbgxBLP19w%3D%3D"

    DestinationFile = "C:\VBA\4750422330.pdf"

    If URLDownloadToFile(0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "file download started"
    Else
        Debug.Print "file download not started"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that your `FileURL` needs to be the actual file that you are needing (which would end with .pdf) when using your API call `URLDownloadToFile` . You are likely just downloading an HTML webpage - and because your output file is `4750422330.pdf` you are storing an HTML page with a .pdf extension.

Comment: <a href="/expotr/expotr?action=com.expd.webapp.tracking.action.document.DocumentImageDownloadWebAction&amp;Type=Image.Get&amp;xref=IVP9OABdjwlQyfAP4d8VNzKeBtYse1TlCWJmb5gzyMxbwbgxBLP19w%3D%3D" target="_blank">Commercial Invoice</a>

Comment: When i manually search above URL in internet browser, document get open and get option save in PDF, above is my HTML page link reference

Comment: Right - but the url itself is to a webpage. It's not a direct link to your file, therefore you are not able to use `URLDownloadToFile`. A direct link to a file will always end with the file's extension. You may be able to scrape the html document's elements for the file's url, but I can't help you there without seeing the html code of the document.

Comment: I have shared the HTML code in my previous comments

Comment: i have a similar script for different URL however file extension is "jpg", this is working even though fileurl doesnt end with.jpg                                          
 pod = Trim(Sheets("PDF2Edoc").Cells(a, 1).Value)
FileURL = "http://spoton.co.in/SPOTTRACK/Advance/getpod.aspx?id=" & pod & "&mPODDw=Y"
 DestinationFile = src & pod & ".jpg"
 URLDownloadToFile 0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0

Comment: can you please advise what details you required to help me on this subject?

Comment: thank you for all your suggestion, i am able to find the solution, the issue was, i was not navigating documents link URL and waiting to web page to load because of that script downloading HTML page instead of actual documents, now its working without any error.

Comment: Hello i am again facing same issue, file has been damaged, can someone help pleas, script already mentioned above, let me know if anything required to check from my side.